# How to replace multiple strings in one go?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am looking for a way to replace multiple strings in the same div that has the class name "information". This div appears multiple times on the page and I would like it to work in each instance.

I have managed find a way to achieve with the code below, however this way seems most likely very clunky.

Is there a way to condense this so it doesnt repeat so much and can check by class, then replace each string required?

```
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var pages = str.replace(" pages", "&nbsp;pp.");
    elements[i].innerHTML = pages;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var page = str.replace(" page", "&nbsp;p.");
    elements[i].innerHTML = page;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var colours = str.replace("colour &amp; ", "colour&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;");
    elements[i].innerHTML = colours;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var illustrations = str.replace(" ill", "&nbsp;ill");
    elements[i].innerHTML = illustrations;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var multiplication = str.replace(" × ", "&nbsp;×&nbsp;");
    elements[i].innerHTML = multiplication;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var cm = str.replace(" cm", "&nbsp;cm");
    elements[i].innerHTML = cm;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var langauge = str.replace(" / ", "&ThinSpace;/&ThinSpace;");
    elements[i].innerHTML = langauge;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `.replaceAll()` instead of `.replace()`, or use a regex with the "g" flag with `.replace()`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that a quick search (like, "MDN string replace") can answer for you.

Comment: Why do you keep reassigning `elements` with the same value? Do you think it's going to change after each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just repeat `str = str.replace...` for each pattern:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;

    str = str.replace(" pages", "&nbsp;pp.");
    str = str.replace(" page", "&nbsp;p.");
    str = str.replace("colour &amp; ", "colour&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;");
    //....etc
    
    elements[i].innerHTML = str;
}
```

Also, you most probably want [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), not just `replace`.

Comment: Why replace `page` twice?

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I created an array of the changes, each element having two elements the first being what is replaced and the second is what will replace it.

Then I simply loop through the elements using a forEach and through the array and use each element to replace on innerHTML.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll(".information");
const changes = [
  [" pages", "&nbsp;pp."],
  [" page", "&nbsp;p."],
  ["colour &amp; ", "colour&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;"],
  [" ill", "&nbsp;ill"],
  [" × ", "&nbsp;×&nbsp;"],
  [" cm", "&nbsp;cm"],
  [" / ", "&ThinSpace;/&ThinSpace;"]
]

els.forEach((el) => {
  changes.forEach((ch) => el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replaceAll(ch[0],ch[1]))
});
```

```html
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information"> pages &nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information"> page &nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / ggggg</div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
<div class="information">&nbsp; ill test x / </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### RegExp?

You can use regex to replace specific string patterns, it looks like this:

```js
for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('information')) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
    .replace(/( pages)/, '&nbsp;pp.')
    .replace(/( page)/, '&nbsp;p.')
    .replace(/(colour.[&;amp]*)/, 'colour&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;')
    .replace(/( ill)/, '&nbsp;ill')
    .replace(/( x ?)/, '&nbsp;×&nbsp;')
    .replace(/( cm)/, '&nbsp;cm')
    .replace(/( \/ )/, '&ThinSpace;/&ThinSpace;')
}
```

```css
body {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fcbe24;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="information"> pages</div>
<div class="information"> page</div>
<div class="information">colour &amp; </div>
<div class="information"> ill</div>
<div class="information"> x </div>
<div class="information"> cm</div>
<div class="information"> / </div>
```